# how to align login form wp_login_form()

Tags: wordpress, authentication, customization

I'd like to customize my WordPress Login form. I am a newbie in WP and strictly follows procedure described here:`https://themetrust.com/build-custom-wordpress-login-page/`.  But I made additional small customization:

```
require_once( explode( "wp-content" , __FILE__ )[0] . "wp-load.php" );

get_header(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<style>
.right{
position: absolute;
right: 532px;
width: 480px;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<?php
$args = array(
'echo'           => true,
'redirect'       => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 
'form_id'        => 'loginform',
'label_username' => 'Username',
'label_password' => 'Password',
'label_remember' => 'Remember Me',
'label_log_in'   => 'Log In',
'id_username'    => 'user_login',
'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
'remember'       => true,
'value_username' => NULL,
'value_remember' => false 
);
?> 
 <div>
<table class = "right" bgcolor="#cccccc">
<tr>
 <td <p><a href="<?php  get_template_directory_uri() .'/page-not-
member.php'; ?>">Not member yet</a></p></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2">Login:</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> <?php wp_login_form( array('redirect' => home_url()) ); ?> </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><a href="<?php get_template_directory_uri() 
.'/zapomnij_formularz.php'; ?>">Forgot password?</a></td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

... and I got Login page like this:
`http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/image1.1499330136.jpg`

How can i get page formatted like that(login/password input fields aligned ): `http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/image2.1499330556.jpg`?

```
Thank you in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css.Below css are login form css.

Here's some helpful, highly specifc CSS selectors for the login page:

```
body.login {}
body.login div#login {}
body.login div#login h1 {}
body.login div#login h1 a {}
body.login div#login form#loginform {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p label {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input#user_login {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input#user_pass {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.forgetmenot {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.forgetmenot input#rememberme {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.submit {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.submit input#wp-submit {}
body.login div#login p#nav {}
body.login div#login p#nav a {}
body.login div#login p#backtoblog {}
body.login div#login p#backtoblog a {}
```

for you i think thione css is needed

```
body.login div#login form#loginform input#user_pass {}
```

Hopes this helps you

Comment: Thanks. But I have another question. I installed WordPress(WP) locally on my PC in some folder(=my site). I made successful registration as administrator and  login on WP.  But problem is - I don't see WP login form when I'd like to login next time. I can't see and check how is looking like my customized form. I cleared cookies(as recomended) and no result.  I just redirected onto WP admin page without any loging pages. Only full reinstallation of my local server and WordPress...

Comment: For local installation what server you are using? E.g:wamp,zamp

Comment: It is not a problem of installer. I use OpenServer. (Wamp or XAMPP not working properly). I made everything desribed here `https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form` , made logout from admin ( backend) and nothing changed. I don't logout from my  site directly, 'cause it is not working correctly and hang up login page...